# c++ library for simplify repetitive task on internet?

Tags: html, c++, html-manipulation

I need some advice, link, source code or tutorials for simplifying repetitive task over the internet. Let's say that I want download some video from vimeo very often, or login in my gmail account, etc... and for that purpose I want to programmatically from c++ solve that task. So what I mainly need is some free library for working with html, so that I can scan for example gmail and in right place put my account notification and press login button, or scan site like vimeo, and in them find code that refers to download and execute download process,....

Comment: Do you have to use C++ for this?

Comment: i have most programing experiance in c++, but if you have better suggestion let me know ...

Answer (score 2):

Hi i think you can look for [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) it support many protocols

Comment: very nice, but I need take a serious look to see real power of that ..:)

Comment: @raptor I can give you my recomendation for this lib. In two last  my projects  i use it and there is no any problems detected